# Get work items by column name in TFS backlog board

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I have a board with customized columns in my backlog. Is there any way to get all *user stories* in a specific column?

I have two columns with same state 'active', so I cannot filter by state, I need to do it by column name. For instance, I need to get 'user stories' in column 'A' (status Active) without return the  'user stories' in column 'B' (also Active).

**Update:** The program does not run on the same computer TFS is installed. I need to do this in client side.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri collectionUri = new Uri("http://tfs-server/tfs");

        TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer =
            TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(collectionUri);

        ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(
            new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection },
            false,
            CatalogQueryOptions.None);

        Guid collectionId = new Guid(collectionNodes[0].Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
        TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);

        var workStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

        var storiesInA = workStore.Query(
                       @" Select [State], [Title] From WorkItems
                        Where
                            [Work Item Type] = 'User Story' and
                            [State] = 'Active' and
                            [System.AreaPath] = 'MyPath'
                        Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kanban columns are specific to a Team and need to be accessed through a team specific context. You can access this through the WorkItemTypeExtensionService in TFS. You can find the answer here:

- [Access the Kanban Column (a Team-Specific Field) for a Work Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193036/access-the-kanban-column-a-team-specific-field-for-a-work-item)

Comment: I added an update, I am programming in other computer than TFS is installed, I dont have server dlls

Comment: Did you figure out how to access it from a computer other than the one with TFS installed?

Comment: This is not available client side yet. You will need to build your own web service to access untill the next version of TFS.

Comment: A good indication of the teams future direction is here: http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-project-teams-vsi